# Right Pattern for Multiple Table Views and Multiple Collection Views

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, design-patterns, uicollectionview

I need to implement a list of items with 2 different views: text list and photo list, similarly to what iBooks on iPad does:

[image: iBooks view type selector]

However, I have 4 different categories of items: movies, music, games and books, each of which have different characteristics and will need different information to be shown. Category will be changed by the user using a drop down menu, and not a tab bar, as the tab bar is already in use (this would the library section of app).

My intention is to use table views for the text lists of items and collection views for the photo lists. For each item category, the data source for both the table view and the collection view could be the same, as the collection view simply presents less information.

My question is which pattern to use. I could have:

- A. 4 table view controllers + 4 collection view controllers
- B. 1 table view controller + 1 collection view controller (which manage 1 table view and 1 collection view respectively, with 4 types of table view cells, 4 types of collection view cells).
- C. 1 table view controller + 1 collection view controller (which manage 4 table views    and 4 collection views respectively)
- D. 4 view controllers (each manage 1 table and 1 collection view, sharing the data source)
- E. 1 view controller (managing everything, 1 table view and 1 collection views, 4 different table view cells, 4 different collection view cells).

I believe solutions A and D should be the cleanest in terms of code, B the simplest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a hybrid approach using B as the main controllers but using controllers for each kind of cells and set this controllers based on the selected category.

**UPDATE**: After rethinking more in the subject I will use the option D. One view controller for each category that acts as data sources and delegates for a table view and a collection view.

Answer (score 0):

I would use B and try not to touch them too much as I add new content.

For the collection view,

- the appearance can be customized with a NIB and maybe `applyLayoutAttributes:` and/or a custom layout per content type (in case you want different animations).
- the actions can be implemented like this: long press gesture recognizer, get the last view pressed using `locationInView:` and `indexPathForItemAtPoint:`, pop a `UIMenuItem`, and apply the action on the view (one way to do it).

For each content type I would put the actions and their implementation on a separate class. You could use a naming convention “content-class-name + Actions” to look for such class, or use a factory pattern in the controller to get it. Then inject whatever services it needs, and pass the action and the model class related to the view that initiated the action. This part works for the table too.